# Specifying account on Amazon CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

So I'm trying to pull some metrics on a DynamoDB table using CloudWatch.  This [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/MonitoringDynamoDB.html) has some information on how to do so.  Specially I'm looking at the following example

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics 
    --namespace AWS/DynamoDB  --metric-name ThrottledRequests 
    --dimensions Name=TableName,Value=TestTable Name=Operation,Value=PutItem 
    --start-time 2014-05-02T00:00:00Z --end-time 2014-05-07T00:00:00Z --period 300 --statistics=Sum example
```

What I don't understand is how this command knows which account (and even which login) to use to access the DynamoDB table.

For my particular setup, I have two AWS accounts (staging and production).  And access keys for each of these are in my C:/.aws/credentials file.  How can I specify which environment I want to point at (each env has a table `MyTable`) that I am looking at but I want to pull metrics for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all very clearly documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

> What I don't understand is how this command knows which account (and
>   even which login) to use to access the DynamoDB table.

It could be using the default profile from the credentials file, or an IAM instance role if running on an EC2 instance.

> How can I specify which environment I want to point at (each env has a
>   table MyTable) that I am looking at but I want to pull metrics for
>   each.

If you have two or more accounts configured, then you specify which one to use via the `--profile` argument.